# Bitbake (e.g. Yocto) hangs in step: parsing recipes

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Bitbake (e.g. Yocto) suddenly hangs in the build step: parsing recipes. It does never reach 100%. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the bitbake cache. E.g.:

```
rm tmp/cache/default-glibc/phyboard-mira-imx6-14/x86_64/*
```